# Is it correct and natural to say "I like travel" meaning I like traveling

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Is possible to say *I like travel* meaning I enjoy the acivity of traveling. If it is possibe, then is there any difference between the following sentence pairs?

> I like **travel**.
>
> I like **traveling**.
>
> I like **air travel**.
>
> I like **traveling by air**

Comment: Does this do it? https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-like-travel-i-like-study.3516980/

Comment: Not really, but thanks! The difference is not discussed here

Answer (score 1):

All are acceptable. They simply treat "travel" as a different type of thing.

> I like travel.

This is treating "travel" as a noun. It's a thing you like.  Some might say things about "nounifying." But I'm not particularly worried, at least in this case.

In particular, "travel" is used here as a mass or uncountable noun.  You get some travel, not one travel.  Though it is possible to refer to "my travels."

> In my travels, I have participated in many colorful local festivals.

You probably would not refer to "one travel" or "several travels."

> I like to travel.

Here, travel is a verb. It's an activity you do.

This process does not work equally well for every possible verb.  Consider the verb "study."

> I need to study a lot to get good grades.

This is fine.

> I need a lot of study to get good grades.

This is less usual though still OK.

> I find study to be very boring.

This is also unusual. Probably most people would say "studying" instead.

> I like study. It is rewarding.

This is very unusual. Probably almost everybody would use "to study" or "studying" instead. (Presuming you could find people who actually do like studying.)